# How many 5-digit falling numbers are there?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> A falling number is an integer whose decimal representation has the
>   property that each digit except the units digit is larger than the one
>   to its right. For example, $96520$ is a falling number but $89642$ is not.
>   How many five-digit falling numbers are there?

I was pretty confident in my answer of ${10 \choose 1} + {10 \choose 2} + {10 \choose 3} + {10 \choose 4} + {10 \choose 5}$, and even saw a [site](http://www.saylor.org/site/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/MA111_countingso-2.pdf) that confirmed it (page 6, question 6), but I just saw a [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1504579/combinations-and-permutations-with-falling-numbers) on here for a similar question where everyone looked certain the answer was simply ${10 \choose 5}$.

Is ${10 \choose 5}$ correct? And if so, can someone explain to me how that summarizes the number of falling numbers and not simply the number of 5-digit numbers?

Comment: The sum $\binom{10}{1} + \binom{10}{2} + \cdots + \binom{10}{10}$ on that site represents the total number of falling numbers.  In particular, the number $\binom{10}{k}$ represents the total number of falling numbers of length $k$.

Comment: I foolishly realized this seconds after I posted the question. Thank you for the elaboration, though.

Answer (score 4):

${10\choose5}$ is correct. You choose 5 different numbers from 0 to 9  and arrange them in descending order which has only one way of arranging

Comment: That is, if you consider a number that starts with $0$ as a $5$-digit number.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation. My one question is how would this result differ from the number of 5-digit numbers that are both falling and not falling? Would that not be 10C5 as well?

Comment: No that is ${10\choose5}\cdot 5!$

Comment: @barak manos When you choose $5$ different number the largest is guaranteed to be at least $4$ so first digit $0$ is not possible.

Comment: @cr001 Okay, now I fully understand it. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

More formally. A falling number is a $5$-tuple of strictly decreasing digits. Denote $\mathcal{F}$ the set of falling numbers, and $\mathcal{S}$ the set of the sets of $5$ distinct digits. The function
$$
\begin{align*}
   \varphi\colon\mathcal{F} & \to \mathcal{S} \\
      (a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5) & \mapsto \{a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5\}
\end{align*}
$$
is bijective. This implies that the two sets $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{S}$
have the same cardinality.